# Create cab file from folder by powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to create cab file of a folder and its files by powershell.
I tried below script but it is giving me error.

```
Param(
  $filepath = "D:\Script", 
  $path = "D:\Script\aCab.cab",
  [switch]$debug
  )
Function New-Cab($path,$files)
{
 $makecab = "makecab.makecab"
 Write-Debug "Creating Cab path is: $path"
 $cab = New-Object -ComObject $makecab
 if(!$?) { $(Throw "unable to create $makecab object")}
 $cab.CreateCab($path,$false,$false,$false)
 ForEach ($file in $files)
 {
 $file = $file.fullname.tostring()
 $fileName = Split-Path -path $file -leaf
 Write-Debug "Adding from $file"
 Write-Debug "File name is $fileName"
 $cab.AddFile($file,$filename)
 }
 Write-Debug "Closing cab $path"
 $cab.CloseCab()
} #end New-Cab

# *** entry point to script ***
if($debug) {$DebugPreference = "continue"}
$files = Get-ChildItem -path $filePath | Where-Object { !$_.psiscontainer }
New-Cab -path $path -files $files
```

**Error :**

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
unable to create makecab.makecab object

At D:\SCCM Script\Cabmaker.ps1:11 char:14
```

I tried to download makecab.exe from Micorosoft but it is not getting downloaded. [MakeCab.exe Link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/cab/2.0/w98nt42kmexp/en-us/cabsdk.exe)

Can somebody advise me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can check if in this list the comobject is present:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Classes -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {
    $_.PSChildName -match '^\w+\.\w+$' -and (Test-Path -Path "$($_.PSPath)\CLSID")
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName
```

The error you have let me think that isn't registerd.

It seems that the [MAKECAB.EXE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367841(VS.85).aspx#1) command is present from windows 2000 in `c:\windows\system32` folder. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310618/en-us) link to documentation

Comment: I checked and makecab.exe is found on my machine. However, when i run above code it doesn't show makecab.exe classes. Is there anything need to be done to upload it properly.

Comment: @404 I'm not so sure, but the comobject is installed only with the sdk. Microsoft ends to public the sdk and I don't know why. Why you don't use makecab.exe in your script?

Comment: I didn't found anything relevant or sample code for makecab.exe

Answer (score 1):

The makecab.makecab COMObject [has been removed](https://books.google.fr/books?id=tZ1CAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT374&dq=function%20new-ddf&hl=fr&pg=PT372#v=onepage&q=utility.%20The%20makecab.makecab%20COM%20object%20was%20removed%20from%20Windows%20Vista) from the operating system beginning with Windows Vista.